# How to sort an array of numeric strings and word strings

Tags: python, ruby, arrays, string, sorting

How would you sort list in Python and array in Ruby like:

```
["car", "z", "9", "bus", "3"]
```

to have this array in return:

```
["bus", "car", "3", "z", "9"]
```

I've started building it in Ruby, because I know it better. I tried .sort with no parameters.
Then I started writing Insertion sort with hopes I will rebuild it to my order and wrote this method.

```
def sort
 @array.each do |value|
   index = @array.index(value)
   i = index - 1
   while i >= 0
     if value < @array[i]
       @array[i + 1] = @array[i]
       @array[i] = value
     elsif (value =~ /\d/) == 0
       # I wanted to do something here, whenever it stops at number to word comparison   but didn't come up with anything workable
     else
       break
     end
   end
 end
```

end

All I can get is
   ["3", "9", "bus", "car", "z"]
 But that's a code challenge I have to complete and the goal is to sort the array of strings in alphabetical and numerical order keeping keeping numeric strings indexes as in original array, just putting them in ascending order. I was thinking to create 2 hashes for numbers with and words having their keys as indexes in original array and sort just the values, and then inject them in correct order in a new array, but wasn't able to write the code for it and still not sure if that would be the best idea.

Comment: First, pick one language. Second, explain why you think that should be the output. Third, show what you have tried so far and describe what exactly the problem with it is.

Comment: And most of all, explain why you think `"3"` should be sorted before `"z"`, but `"9"` comes after. I see no logical progression here.

Comment: Sorry for poor start, it was early morning for me. Just edited it.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because it is clear now, but have a question: if it is a code challenge, isn't the point to solve it yourself instead of asking StackOverflow to do it? (PS your idea is valid, just break it down into discrete steps and you can solve it)

Comment: Hint: 1. Store indices of numeric elements. 2. [`partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) the array. 3. Sort each partition. 4. [`insert`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Array.html#method-i-insert) numeric elements back in.

Comment: Thanks, yes I'll try. The whole challenge is reading a file, sorting, validating length of strings in file and writing it in a new one in Python which is new to me. I've researched the question and Python syntax and decided to write it all up in Ruby and then translation to Python won't be that difficult. File IO and validation of length is a piece of cake. It was just this sort trick tripping me up (Duuh! :D) But I'll make it

Comment: Code challenges, just like homework, are a chance for you to learn how to do something by figuring it out yourself. Asking us to show you how to do it defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: Well I agree. I've spent about 6 hours tackling it, was exausted and decided to ask. It's a problem and one has to find any possible way to solve it. In the end I've got what I needed. Mark Thomas have an awesome hint that made me understand and solve it really fast. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So here is how I've solved it. Thanks to Mark Thomas for hint with partition and insert methods. Please comment on your thoughts and suggestions about efficiency and clarity of code.

```
def sort
  # storing indicies of number strings to map them back later
  num_indicies = @array.map {|i| @array.index(i) if (i =~ /\d/) == 0}.compact
  # if there are no numbers
  if num_indicies.empty?
    @array.sort!
    #if there are only numbers
  elsif num_indicies.length == @array.length
    @array = @array.map {|n| n.to_i}.sort
  else
    # separating numbers and words for proper sort
    separation = @array.partition {|c| (c =~ /\d/) == 0}
    # sorting first array. Converting to integer in order to sort numbers bigger than 10
    separation[0] = separation[0].map {|n| n.to_i}.sort
    # sorting array of words and letters
    separation[1].sort!
    # inserting numbers in their original spots
    index = 0
    separation[0].each do |num|
      #inserting sorted integers inside of array of sorted strings, simultaniously converting them into strings
      @array = separation[1].insert(num_indicies[index], num.to_s)
      # switching index for another iteration
      index += 1
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to find a gem (or write something yourself) that can turn the numbers into their word form.

Like, for instance:

https://github.com/radar/humanize

The rest should be obvious.

Comment: Well, the will mix it up a bit. 293 is two hundred ninty three, which is ["two", "hundred", "ninty", "three"].sort == ["hundred", "ninty", "three", "two"] And that's not the result I need.